# Fullcalendar, want to show all events on dayclick its not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar, once a user clicks on a date the events on that day should show up on the pop up.

Currently I have the list of the events with me , I am able to show the events on that day on calendar and make it clickable.

But now I want those events to show on dayclick which I am not able to do.

Below code shows the events on that day on calendar:

```
eventClick: function(event) {
       $.colorbox({html:"<h1>"+event.title+"</h1><br><p>Tour 
       starts on :"+$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start,
       'yyyy-M-dd')+"<br>Tour type :
       <a href='http://reservations.valantech.com/order-
       tour/"+$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start,'yyyy-M-
       dd')+"/"+event.ID+"'>"+event.type+"</a></p>"});
},
```

Below code open a pop up when a date is clicked:

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

        if (allDay) {
            alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
        }else{
            alert('Clicked on the slot: ' + date);
        }

        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

        alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

        // change the day's background color just for fun
        //$(this).css('background-color', 'red');

    },
```

Now I want to merge these two basically.

Clicking the date should open a pop-up with a list of all available events for that date.

I tried to do :

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
                if(event.start <= date && event.end >= date) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
```

but it didnt worked for me.

Comment: Hey did you got the answer for dayclick showing event? I am searching the same please post your answer thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'basicDay');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date  );
};
```

Comment: it changes the view to the date. In drupal function I was showing the events by writing : drupal_json_output($events); Now it shows the events on the calendar but I want to show it on the date click can you help me how to do it

Comment: My issue is I am able to show it on calendar but I want to show it on day click not on calendar. It was showing on calendar using : drupal_json_output($events);

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.
You can change criteria of return value if return true will return actual event and added to your `array Array`.
and finally you will got `array Array` variable with all events of that date.
Please check the condition as per your requirements.

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    console.log(date);
    $('#agenda_calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'month');
    //$('#agenda_calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date  );
    var array = $('#agenda_calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event){ 
        return ( event.start >= date && event.end < date ); // May be change
    });
    console.log(array);
});
```